# dose dladdr able to get the info from static member?

Tags: c++, c, shared-libraries, dladdr

during reserch of some library I found this kind of code

```
Dl_info info = {
   NULL,
   NULL,
   NULL,
   NULL
};

if (!dladdr((void*) dirSep, &info)) {
   return libPath.c_str();
}
```

where `dirSep` is `static const char*` member in class where this code is present (in come member function), so my question is: is there any place documented that `dladdr` function able get an info form `static const member` field ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, and `dladdr` can't promise or guarantee that. It can only look at the symbol table in the module. If the symbol table contains the symbol, then it can give it to you. If not, not. What symbols are in the symbol table depends on how the module is compiled, how it is linked, and how and whether it is stripped.

Generally speaking, if code could link to it, then `dladdr` should find it.